# Como duplicar um campo Csv em PHP?

Tags: php, php-7

Eu tenho um campo id dentro um arquivo csv que é lido como um array. Esse campo id vem com dois id em um campo pois os id possui um campo de resposta idêntico chamado "resposta". Em vez de repetir esse campo idêntico como (exemplo: ID:2334 REPOSTA: EU SOU LEGAL ID 2187: REPOSTA: EU SOU LEGAL.) a pessoa que fez o csv juntoU os id que possui a mesma resposta idêntico.(EXEMPLO:ID:2334,2187 RESPOSTA: EU SOU LEGAL) Como consigo duplicar esse campo idêntico pelo id quando ler o arquivo csv COMO O EXEMPLO ANOTADO EM CIMA (exemplo: ID:2334 REPOSTA: EU SOU LEGAL ID 2187: REPOSTA: EU SOU LEGAL.)EM PHP???
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
    <?php


ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

include 'utils.php';

// Filename contem o nome do CSV passado por parêmetro na linha de comando
$filename = (count($argv) > 3) ? $argv[3] : '';
// Lê o arquivo e o converte para um array com a lista de dados
$csv = parseCsv($filename);
// Extrai metadados do nome do
$path_parts = pathinfo($filename);

/**
 * Dicionário de colunas.
 * Cada item desse array deve conter a chave igual a coluna do cabeçalho do CSV
 * e no valor o nome da coluna no banco de dados.
 */
$dicionario_colunas = [
    'ID SKU' => 'ID',
    'Categorias de TR relacionadas' => 'CTG_TR_RELACIONADAS',
    'Nº da pergunta' => 'N_PERGUNTAS',
    'Pergunta' => 'PERGUNTA',
    'Tip (i)' => 'TIP',
    'Opções' => 'OPÇÕES',
    'Se SIM' => 'SIM',
    'Se NÃO' => 'NÃO',
];

$csv = normalizeCsvArrayKeys($csv, $dicionario_colunas);

if (empty($csv)) {//verificando se o seu file.csv está vazio
    die("Arquivo csv vazio\n");
}

$perguntas = [];
$duplicate = [];
foreach ($csv as $linha) {
    $perguntaId = trim($linha['ID']);
    if (!array_key_exists($perguntaId, $perguntas)) {
        $perguntas[$perguntaId] = [
            'ID' => $perguntaId,
            'CTG_TR_RELACIONADAS' => trim($linha['CTG_TR_RELACIONADAS']),
            'N_PERGUNTAS' => trim($linha['N_PERGUNTAS']),
            'PERGUNTA' => trim($linha['PERGUNTA']),
            'TIP' => trim($linha['TIP']),
            'OPÇÕES' => trim($linha['OPÇÕES']),
            'SIM' => trim($linha['SIM']),
            'NÃO' => trim($linha['NÃO']),
        ];
    }

}

$migrationID = date('YmdHis');
$migrationRef = 'exames';
$migrationName = $path_parts['filename'];
$outputName = $migrationID . '_' . $migrationRef . '_' . $migrationName . '.sql';
$output = fopen(ROOT . '/db_crx/migrations/' . $outputName, "w"); # not readedlines

try {
    echo "\nProcessando os dados\n";

    echo "Iniciando output.\n";

    fwrite($output, "SET search_path = \"rx_ref\";\n");
    fwrite($output, 'BEGIN;' . "\n\n");

    fwrite($output, "UPDATE tr_equipamento_perguntas SET obsoleto = NOW();\n");
    fwrite($output, "UPDATE tr_equipamentos SET obsoleto = NOW();\n");

    if (!empty($perguntas)) {
        fwrite($output, "\n" . "-- insert / update tr_fabricantes\n");
        foreach ($perguntas as $perg) {
            $stmt = "INSERT INTO tr_equipamento_perguntas (tr_equipamento_id, ordem_pergunta, pergunta, dica_1,resposta_sim,resposta_nao) VALUES (" .
                "'{$perg['ID']}', '{$perg['N_PERGUNTAS']}', '{$perg['PERGUNTA']}', '{$perg['TIP']}','{$perg['SIM']}', '{$perg['NÃO']}')\n" .
                "ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET NúmeroPergunta = '{$perg['N_PERGUNTAS']}', Pergunta = '{$perg['PERGUNTA']}', Dica = '{$perg['TIP']}',
                RespostaSim = '{$perg['SIM']}', RespostaNão = '{$perg['NÃO']}'," .
                "obsoleto = null;\n";
            fwrite($output, $stmt);
        }
    }


    fwrite($output, "DELETE FROM tr_equipamento_perguntas WHERE obsoleto IS NOT NULL;\n");

    fwrite($output, "\n" .
        "INSERT INTO public.crx_migrations (id, reference, description, filename) VALUES ('$migrationID', '$migrationRef', '$migrationName', '$outputName');\n");

    fwrite($output, "\nCOMMIT;\n");
    echo "Output pronto.\nVerifique o arquivo $outputName na pasta de migrações\n";

}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "\n" . "Ocorreu uma exceção durante a geração do script:\n";
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    echo $e->getTraceAsString() . "\n";

    if (file_exists($output)) {
        unlink($output);
    }
}
```

Comment: Rapaz, ficou um pouco confuso sua pergunta tem como esclarecer melhor ?

Comment: Eu tenho um arquivo csv que normalmente preciso converter para arquivo sql em php. eu ja consegui fazer. mas tenho somente um problema. tenho dois campo: 1 chamado ID e outro chamado de RESPOSTA. quando o arquivo csv foi criado, a pessoa não quis se dar o trabalho de repetir campos que tinha como resposta indentico. exempplo: ID = A , REPOSTA= 23  E ID = B, RESPOSTA 23. Como os dois tem a mesma resposta, a pessoas junto os id em um campo e ficou ID= A,B RESPOSTA= 23. ja coloco uma imagem para entender melhor

Comment: no caso os quadros selecionados, o primeiro id é o id pergunta, e o segundo id seria o id resposta ? e a resposta é o segundo quadro marcado em vermelho ?

Comment: o campo "ID SKUL" dentro da imagem que postei ai em cima, se refere ao  ID como no exemplo de ID= A e ID= B. Que selecionei em quadros vermelho,Agora o campo Se Sim S se refere ao RESPOSTA como no exemplo que deixei la pra vc RESPOTA =23.  também selecionei em vermelho. Agora dentro desse "ID SKULL" voce pode perceber que tem uns campo que veio com dois numero de id. exemplo: TD003,TD004. Esses dois foram colocados là pq a resposta da coluna Se sim é a mesma para os dois, Não sei se fiquei mais claro?

Comment: Está clareado, no caso o no caso de existirem 2 ID SKU você precisa inserir 2 vezes no banco a resposta em questão ? por exemplo id 3 e 4, inserir a resposta "Teste..." ?

Comment: isso mesmo @Bulfaitelo

Comment: Vou responder com a ideia do que você pode fazer, pra ficar mais fácil de compreender. mas a parte de ler o arquivo e fácil pra tu né e teria como colocar, uma linha com 2 id e uma linha com apenas um 1 ai na pergunta para eu ter como base pra montar uma lógica?

Comment: eu vou colocar o codigo inteiro la na pergunta pq aqui não da paar colocar tudo por causa dos caracteres....

Comment: Só por desencargo de duvida, `$perguntaId` recebe : `TD002` ou `TD003;TD004`?

Comment: Tem campo a onde o Id vem sozinho e outros campos o id vem dois ou três em um campo só como no exemplo de TD003;TD004 por causa do que expliquei la em cima. Não sei vc entendeu ou ainda ficou com dúvida?

Comment: Eu entendi a pergunta se ele vem dessa forma separados por";"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando como base o que discutimos, e seu código já pronto, o que fiz,

Criei um vetor com os dados de `$perguntaId` utilizando o explode com o delimitador `";"`, fiz a contagem e caso tenhamos um vetor com 2 ou ou mais, que dizer que existem 2 ids ou mais para serem inseridos no banco de dados.

Após isso com base nesse vetor eu percorro um `foreach();` atualizando o vetor `$perguntas` seguindo a mesma lógica to que já temos, porem replicando os outros dados para esses ids, salvos no banco.

Por exemplo: caso caso tenhamos o id `0003`,`0004`, com a resposta `jujuba`, tanto a `0003` e a `004` terão o valor da resposta como `jujuba`

**Segue todo o código:**

```
<?php  

ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

include 'utils.php';

// Filename contem o nome do CSV passado por parêmetro na linha de comando
$filename = (count($argv) > 3) ? $argv[3] : '';
// Lê o arquivo e o converte para um array com a lista de dados
$csv = parseCsv($filename);
// Extrai metadados do nome do
$path_parts = pathinfo($filename);

/**
 * Dicionário de colunas.
 * Cada item desse array deve conter a chave igual a coluna do cabeçalho do CSV
 * e no valor o nome da coluna no banco de dados.
 */
$dicionario_colunas = [
    'ID SKU' => 'ID',
    'Categorias de TR relacionadas' => 'CTG_TR_RELACIONADAS',
    'Nº da pergunta' => 'N_PERGUNTAS',
    'Pergunta' => 'PERGUNTA',
    'Tip (i)' => 'TIP',
    'Opções' => 'OPÇÕES',
    'Se SIM' => 'SIM',
    'Se NÃO' => 'NÃO',
];

$csv = normalizeCsvArrayKeys($csv, $dicionario_colunas);

if (empty($csv)) {//verificando se o seu file.csv está vazio
    die("Arquivo csv vazio\n");
}

$perguntas = [];
$duplicate = [];
foreach ($csv as $linha) {
    $perguntaId = trim($linha['ID']);
    // caso exista 2 opção eu crio um vetor para tal. 
    $arrayPerguntaId = explode(';', $perguntaId);
    if(count($arrayPerguntaId)>1){
        // percorro o array e replico os dados. 
        foreach ($arrayPerguntaId as $key => $arrayValue) {
            if (!array_key_exists($arrayValue, $perguntas)) {
                $perguntas[$arrayValue] = [
                    'ID' => $arrayValue,
                    'CTG_TR_RELACIONADAS' => trim($linha['CTG_TR_RELACIONADAS']),
                    'N_PERGUNTAS' => trim($linha['N_PERGUNTAS']),
                    'PERGUNTA' => trim($linha['PERGUNTA']),
                    'TIP' => trim($linha['TIP']),
                    'OPÇÕES' => trim($linha['OPÇÕES']),
                    'SIM' => trim($linha['SIM']),
                    'NÃO' => trim($linha['NÃO']),
                ];
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (!array_key_exists($perguntaId, $perguntas)) {
            $perguntas[$perguntaId] = [
                'ID' => $perguntaId,
                'CTG_TR_RELACIONADAS' => trim($linha['CTG_TR_RELACIONADAS']),
                'N_PERGUNTAS' => trim($linha['N_PERGUNTAS']),
                'PERGUNTA' => trim($linha['PERGUNTA']),
                'TIP' => trim($linha['TIP']),
                'OPÇÕES' => trim($linha['OPÇÕES']),
                'SIM' => trim($linha['SIM']),
                'NÃO' => trim($linha['NÃO']),
            ];
        }
    }
}

$migrationID = date('YmdHis');
$migrationRef = 'exames';
$migrationName = $path_parts['filename'];
$outputName = $migrationID . '_' . $migrationRef . '_' . $migrationName . '.sql';
$output = fopen(ROOT . '/db_crx/migrations/' . $outputName, "w"); # not readedlines

try {
    echo "\nProcessando os dados\n";

    echo "Iniciando output.\n";

    fwrite($output, "SET search_path = \"rx_ref\";\n");
    fwrite($output, 'BEGIN;' . "\n\n");

    fwrite($output, "UPDATE tr_equipamento_perguntas SET obsoleto = NOW();\n");
    fwrite($output, "UPDATE tr_equipamentos SET obsoleto = NOW();\n");

    if (!empty($perguntas)) {
        fwrite($output, "\n" . "-- insert / update tr_fabricantes\n");
        foreach ($perguntas as $perg) {
            $stmt = "INSERT INTO tr_equipamento_perguntas (tr_equipamento_id, ordem_pergunta, pergunta, dica_1,resposta_sim,resposta_nao) VALUES (" .
                "'{$perg['ID']}', '{$perg['N_PERGUNTAS']}', '{$perg['PERGUNTA']}', '{$perg['TIP']}','{$perg['SIM']}', '{$perg['NÃO']}')\n" .
                "ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET NúmeroPergunta = '{$perg['N_PERGUNTAS']}', Pergunta = '{$perg['PERGUNTA']}', Dica = '{$perg['TIP']}',
                RespostaSim = '{$perg['SIM']}', RespostaNão = '{$perg['NÃO']}'," .
                "obsoleto = null;\n";
            fwrite($output, $stmt);
        }
    }


    fwrite($output, "DELETE FROM tr_equipamento_perguntas WHERE obsoleto IS NOT NULL;\n");

    fwrite($output, "\n" .
        "INSERT INTO public.crx_migrations (id, reference, description, filename) VALUES ('$migrationID', '$migrationRef', '$migrationName', '$outputName');\n");

    fwrite($output, "\nCOMMIT;\n");
    echo "Output pronto.\nVerifique o arquivo $outputName na pasta de migrações\n";

}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "\n" . "Ocorreu uma exceção durante a geração do script:\n";
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    echo $e->getTraceAsString() . "\n";

    if (file_exists($output)) {
        unlink($output);
    }
}
```

**Somente o que eu adicionei:**

```
// caso exista 2 opção eu crio um vetor para tal. 
    $arrayPerguntaId = explode(';', $perguntaId);
    if(count($arrayPerguntaId)>1){
        // percorro o array e replico os dados. 
        foreach ($arrayPerguntaId as $key => $arrayValue) {
            if (!array_key_exists($arrayValue, $perguntas)) {
                $perguntas[$arrayValue] = [
                    'ID' => $arrayValue,
                    'CTG_TR_RELACIONADAS' => trim($linha['CTG_TR_RELACIONADAS']),
                    'N_PERGUNTAS' => trim($linha['N_PERGUNTAS']),
                    'PERGUNTA' => trim($linha['PERGUNTA']),
                    'TIP' => trim($linha['TIP']),
                    'OPÇÕES' => trim($linha['OPÇÕES']),
                    'SIM' => trim($linha['SIM']),
                    'NÃO' => trim($linha['NÃO']),
                ];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Valeu @Bulfaitelo eu vou testar ai para ver o que rola e depois deixo um feedback.Obrigado por ajudar realmente. :)

Comment: Testa sim, e me fala, mas atenta que eu usei a lógica com base no `";"` como divisor

Comment: Pode deixar que eu vou testar e aviso aqui se funcionar ou não :)

Comment: Você me salvou @Bulfaitelo :) Obrigado pela força camarada